# how to cope with the git repo sync failure

Tags: github

I use the github windows client. When I move the mouse to  the "sync" button, it tell me "ahead by 2 commits, behind by 0 commits", so I click the sync, but then the github client remind me that "failed to sync this branch. You might need to open a shell and debug the state of this repo.

How should I do?  I do not know how to cope with it.